Proving Uniform Boundedness
I'm working on a problem involving the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, and I need help proving that a sequence of functions is uniformly bounded. Here’s the setup:
Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions in $C^1([0,1])$, meaning each $f_n$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$. Suppose that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$\left|f_n'(x)\right| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for all $x \in (0,1]$.
$\int_0^1 f_n(x) \, dx = 0$.

I would like to show that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $[0,1]$, so that I can apply the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem to conclude that a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.
Here’s my approach:

Estimating $f_n(0)$:
$
   f_n(0) = \int_0^1 (f_n(0) - f_n(x)) \, dx,
   $
so
$
   |f_n(0)| \leq \int_0^1 |f_n(0) - f_n(x)| \, dx.
   $
Using $|f_n(x) - f_n(0)| \leq 2\sqrt{x}$, I get
$
   |f_n(0)| \leq \int_0^1 2\sqrt{x} \, dx = \frac{4}{3}.
   $

Bounding $f_n(x)$:
$
   |f_n(x)| \leq |f_n(0)| + 2\sqrt{x} \leq \frac{4}{3} + 2 = \frac{10}{3}.
   $


Does this approach correctly show that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $[0,1]$?
Thank you in advance for your help!

try using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the triangle inequality for integrals.

Thank you for your input, I updated my question and added the approach I used. May you check to me please if it is correct?

Perfect! Your proof is correct.

Thank you so much for your feedback!
